# Does it make sense for a model te be a subtype of a model, if it shares similar API but is not essentially a subtype?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `Ticket` model, which has polymorphic relationship with its subtypes, `EquipmentTicket` and `OfficeSuppliesTicket`.

After support receives a ticket, they need to submit a `PurchaseOrder` based on that ticket to HR. `PurchaseOrder` behaves like a ticket and has similar API, but considering business logic, it makes sense to me that these two terms are different.

I feel like there's a bit of a duplication when treating `PurchaseOrder` as a separate entity, but does the other choice make sense?

Comment: When you say "business logic" isnt' that something a controller should handle?

Comment: Would [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) be an option for you?

Comment: I'm refering to business logic as what makes more sense to the business. So, it doesn't make sense for `PurchaseOrder` to be a subtype when it's not how you talk about it. So it's like a ticket, but not really a ticket.

How can dependency injection help?

Comment: @shaedrich Business logic belongs in a model, not a controller. @Ogatron3000 Domain Driven Design has a concept called [`Bounded Context`](https://thedomaindrivendesign.io/bounded-context/) where the same object can have different meaning and subtle differences in functionality depending on where it is used. Duplication is accepted in this scenario as it makes sense to not leak logic between the contexts.

Comment: @Ogatron3000 With dependency injection, you could inject the API class instead extending from it.

Comment: @Peppermintology If I understand you and the article correctly, I should treat `PurchaseOrder` as a different object because it's in a different context - it's a document between support and HR, while ticket is a document between user and support.

Comment: @Ogatron3000 Correct. Even if two objects share a lot of the same structure/functionality, if they have subtle differences and makes sense to have them as independent objects then don't be afraid to treat them as such.